# SELECT nearest under or equal to X based on SUM amount SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
Declare @tbitems TABLE (accntno varchar, saved_amount decimal)
INSERT INTO @tbitems
SELECT 001     ,  25

Declare @tbtransact TABLE (idno INT , acctno varchar, amount decimal)
INSERT INTO @tbtransact
SELECT 1 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 001 ,  10
```

**tbitems**:

```
accntno | saved_amount (decimal)
--------+-----------------------
001     |  25
```

**tbtransact**:

```
idno  | acctno  | amount (decimal)
------+---------+-----------------
1     | 001     |  10
2     | 001     |  10
3     | 001     |  10
4     | 001     |  10
```

How do I get the nearest idno with less than or equal to the `saved_amount` from `tbitems` by adding `tbtransact` amounts ordered by idno (I really don't know how to say it in words).

Anyway based on my table, my expected result should be idno 2 since the nearest under 25 is 20

If I would to do it in java, I would loop through tbtransact then add every row until I go higher than the saved_amount then get the idno before the current one. However I have no idea how to do it in sql.

Expected result is:

```
idno  | acctno  | amount
------+---------+-----------------
2     | 001     |  10
```

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query works for selecting the correct row for a specific account:

```
SELECT TOP 1
        t.idno ,
        s.*
FROM    dbo.tbitems AS i
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbtransact AS t ON i.accntno = t.acctno
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    SUM(l.amount) AS SumAmount
                      FROM      dbo.tbtransact AS l
                      WHERE     l.acctno = t.acctno
                                AND l.idno <= t.idno
                    ) AS s
WHERE   i.accntno = '001' AND s.SumAmount <= i.saved_amount
ORDER BY s.SumAmount DESC;
```

And this should word accross multipse accounts:

```
SELECT t.acctno, MAX(idno) AS idno, MAX(s.SumAmount) AS SumAmount
FROM    dbo.tbitems AS i
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbtransact AS t ON i.accntno = t.acctno
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    SUM(l.amount) AS SumAmount
                      FROM      dbo.tbtransact AS l
                      WHERE     l.acctno = t.acctno
                                AND l.idno <= t.idno
                    ) AS s
WHERE   s.SumAmount <= i.saved_amount
GROUP BY t.acctno
```

Here is an example using CTE and windowing function:

```
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   t.acctno ,
                        t.amount ,
                        SUM(t.amount) OVER ( PARTITION BY t.acctno ORDER BY t.acctno, t.idno 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS RunningTotal
               FROM     dbo.tbtransact AS t
                        INNER JOIN dbo.tbitems AS i ON t.acctno = i.accntno
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY cte1.acctno ORDER BY cte1.RunningTotal DESC ) AS rn ,
                        cte1.acctno ,
                        cte1.amount ,
                        cte1.RunningTotal
               FROM     cte1
             )
    SELECT  cte2.acctno ,
            cte2.amount ,
            cte2.RunningTotal
    FROM    cte2
    WHERE   cte2.rn = 1;
```

Comment: No reason to use `CROSS APPLY`, SQL Server allows you to calculate running totals with the `OVER` clause. In any case, this would only work for a *single* account

Comment: That's correct. However, you can't use windowing functions in the WHERE clause - so we'd had to use a CTE...

Answer (score 0):

i tried ,it may helps you

```
Declare @tbitems TABLE (accntno INT , saved_amount decimal)
INSERT INTO @tbitems
SELECT 001     ,  25

Declare @tbtransact TABLE (idno INT , acctno INT , amount decimal)
INSERT INTO @tbtransact
SELECT 1 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 001 ,  10

SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t.idno, 
               t.acctno, 
               t.amount, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Sum(saved_amount) 
                        OVER( 
                          partition BY i.accntno 
                          ORDER BY t.idno) <= i.saved_amount THEN i.saved_amount  
                 ELSE 0 
               END AS Nearest_Saved_amount 
        FROM   @tbtransact t 
               INNER JOIN @tbitems i 
                       ON i.accntno = t.acctno)Dt 
WHERE  Dt.Nearest_Saved_amount  <> 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood the question the first time. This should do it:

```
    Declare @tbitems TABLE (accntno INT , saved_amount decimal)
    INSERT INTO @tbitems
    SELECT 001     ,  20

    Declare @tbtransact TABLE (idno INT , acctno INT , amount decimal)
    INSERT INTO @tbtransact
    SELECT 1 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 , 001 ,  10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 , 001 ,  10


    SELECT TOP 1 ttotal.*
    FROM @tbtransact t
    JOIN (
        SELECT idno, acctno,  (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @tbtransact WHERE acctno = ttemp.acctno and idno <= ttemp.idno) AS Amount 
        FROM @tbtransact ttemp
        WHERE idno <= idno
        GROUP BY idno, acctno
    ) AS ttotal on t.acctno = ttotal.acctno
    INNER JOIN @tbitems i ON t.acctno = i.accntno
    WHERE ttotal.Amount <= i.saved_amount
    ORDER BY ttotal.Amount DESC
```

Comment: My tbtransact do have the same amounts so I have to add them then see if the the sum is already higher than the saved_amount.